How to remove 'section 1'?
I have a problem with quarto beamer. I want to remove the word "Section 1" when I start the new section. Or, can we customize the "Section 1"?
---
title: "Markov Chain"
author: "Fariz"
format:
  beamer:
    theme: Boadilla
    colortheme: whale
---

## 

1. Introduction (Ch 4.1)
2. Chapman-Kolmogorov Equations (Ch 4.2)
3. Classification of States (Ch 4.3)

# Introduction (Ch 4.1)

## Deifinition of Markov Chains


I have tried several solutions, but nothing worked. The solution I need is directly in the quarto document without using external latex template.

You can defined your own section page:
---
title: "Markov Chain"
author: "Fariz"
format:
  beamer:
    theme: Boadilla
    colortheme: whale
header-includes:
- \setbeamertemplate{section page}{\centering\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{part title}\usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par\end{beamercolorbox}}
---

## 

1. Introduction (Ch 4.1)
2. Chapman-Kolmogorov Equations (Ch 4.2)
3. Classification of States (Ch 4.3)

# Introduction (Ch 4.1)

## Deifinition of Markov Chains



I was wondering what's wrong with the solutions I get. Now I understand.
I was using
includes:
in-header:
command. Where it should be header-includes: .
Thanks a lot!

@FarizBudiArafat I think quarto has several way to add stuff to the preamble. The header-includes one was just the one I happen to know.
